# Quit the forbbiden cursor while dragging

Tags: html, angular, drag-and-drop, drag

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIBWr.jpg

i want to quit the forbbiden cursor while im dragging an element. im using html5 default drag and drop. im using typescript

ive tried to change from ev.target.style.cursor to the "grab" cursor, i tried to change from dropEffect and so on, but none of them make the desire effect. here is the drag code.

```
<code>
drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed ="copy";
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    this.evdrag = ev.srcElement;
    console.log(ev);

  }
</code>
```

html template:

```
< div [ngClass]="{'dragged': dragged}" class="btn dragword text-center text-lowercase"
                style="font-size: 27px; color: rgb(115, 115, 115); height: 44px" id="Repellendus" draggable="true"
                (dragstart)="drag($event);">Repellendus
```

typescript drop code:

```
<code>drop(ev, index) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (this.data != '') {
      return;
    }
  this.optionHover1 = false;
    this.data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    this.evdrag.remove();
    // ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(this.data));
    this.checkAnswer(this.data, index);
  }</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS in your stylesheet instead.

```
.dragging,
.dragword:active{
    cursor:move!important;
}
```

Without a StackBlitz I can't really recreate this but here is another idea.

**Template (view)**

What about adding a `dragging` class for when it is being dragged?

```
<div [ngClass]="{'dragging': dragging, 'dragging':dragging}" class="btn dragword" id="Repellendus" draggable="true(dragstart)="drag($event);">Repellendus</div>
</pre>
```

**TypeScript**

What about adding the class during the drag event?

```
element.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
  // add `dragging` class
}, false);

element.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
  // remove `dragging` class
}, false);
```

In Angular we'd use `@Hostlistener` though. Here is my personal [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hostlistener-dom-traversal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts) reference for that.

**Sidenote:**

Does each dragword div have the same id? `id="Repellendus"` There must be several of these right?

Comment: thanks for your time, but it doesnt work. its still shows the default forbbiden cursor while i draggin. when i click on i click on it the cursor move shows, but when i drag to other place, the default forbbiden cursor shows :(

Comment: Ok questions time, I'd like to help more. Can you post more of your code? Let's make sure your mouseDown (drag) event is setup properly.

Comment: Sorry mate, im a beginer to this, what are you talking about when you talk about mouseDown? the html template? or the drop?, ill send both.

Comment: each div has its particular id, the info that is send to the drop zone. the @hostlistener its to change style when draggin the element? ive tried changing the classes when draggin but still same forbbiden cursor appears, this one that i post right now in the first comment

Comment: You'll have to replicate this in a Stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

```
html template: <pre>< div [ngClass]="{'dragged': dragged}" class="btn dragword text-center text-lowercase"
                style="font-size: 27px; color: rgb(115, 115, 115); height: 44px" id="Repellendus" draggable="true"
                (dragstart)="drag($event);">Repellendus</ div></pre>

typescript drop code:


 <code>drop(ev, index) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (this.data != '') {
      return;
    }
  this.optionHover1 = false;
    this.data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    this.evdrag.remove();
    // ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(this.data));
    this.checkAnswer(this.data, index);
  }</code>
```

Comment: I would add this to your question and format it super nice! Then you'll get more answers too!